# Why does the Obx (from GetX package) not work in function?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
                          Obx(() => controller.commentList.isEmpty
                          ? const EmptyView()
                          : ListView.separated(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                
                                bool hasReplyingComment = controller.checkHasReplyingComment(index);

                                return CommentCell(
                                  key: controller.commentKeyList[index],
                                  nickname: nickName,
                                  content: content,
                                  date: date,
                                  hasReplyingComment: hasReplyingComment,
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return const SizedBox(height: 20);
                              },
                              itemCount: controller.commentList.length,
                            ))
```

When I add to commentList new comment in controller(Getx), Obx update ListView.

But hasReplyingComment intialize all Comments.

The values that used to meet the condition "hasreplyingComment" well are disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

The `Obx` widget in GetX rebuilds the widget tree when the observable it's listening to changes. In your case, `controller.commentList` might be triggering the rebuild of the `ListView.builder`, but the `hasReplyingComment` variable is not being updated accordingly for each comment cell.

Try this:

```
ListView.separated(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    bool hasReplyingComment = controller.checkHasReplyingComment(index);

    return CommentCell(
      key: controller.commentKeyList[index],
      nickname: nickName,
      content: content,
      date: date,
      hasReplyingComment: hasReplyingComment,
    );
  },
  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return const SizedBox(height: 20);
  },
  itemCount: controller.commentList.length,
)
```